# Alter field text of the view in Drupal View

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view

I have a view for taxonomy term. And show the list of nodes. I need to alter field text (link element). I try to use views_pre_render hook. in it i do something like this:
 foreach ($view->result as $key => &$result);
 $result->field_field_show_buy_tickets[0] (it s my field) and in this array I have ['raw'], ['rendered'] and I need to change link title.

Comment: Could you update your questions with some of the example what are you trying to achieve? Couldn't figure out the issue with your question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear from your question what you're trying to achieve.

Assuming you want to change the link text in a view, you could go to the field configuration/settings in your view and try using rewrite options and replacement patterns

Alternatively you could look at views-view-fields.tpl.php and/or template_preprocess_views_view_fields.

Also, check out [this discussion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84458/how-to-insert-values-into-global-custom-text-field-of-views-programmatically)